# Factory Interface in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm a Ninject user that try to learn Simple Injector

One Ninject feture that I often use in my applications is the [Factory Interface](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki/Factory-interface)

With that I can create a Interface like this:

```
public interface IBarFactory
{
   Bar CreateBar();
}
```

And the register it like this

```
kernel.Bind<IBarFactory>().ToFactory();
```

Then I simple can use IBarFactory, and don't have to create a implementation of IBarFactory

I now try to find anything similar in Simple njector, and have found [this](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How-to#Register-Factory-Delegates). 
But with that approacher, I have to implement the factory interface (more code). And how do I do if the Bar object need a reference to another object?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Simple Injector lacks this a factory interface facility. The idea behind this omission is that when applying Dependency Injection correctly, [the need for using factories is minimized](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2016/abstract-factories-are-a-code-smell/), which makes the usefulness of such feature limited.

In Simple Injector you have to write an implementation yourself, but this is usually trivial. Example:

```
private sealed class SimpleInjectorBarFactory : IBarFactory
{
    private readonly Container container; 
    public SimpleInjectorBarFactory(Container container) => this.container = container;
    public Bar CreateBar() => this.container.GetInstance<Bar>();
}
```

This class can be registered like this:

```
container.RegisterSingleton<IBarFactory, SimpleInjectorBarFactory>();
```

Or -if you're lazy- you can register a `Func<Bar>` to be injected as follows:

```
container.RegisterInstance<Func<Bar>>(() => container.GetInstance<Bar>());
```

Note that since this `SimpleInjectorBarFactory` implementation depends on the `Container` instance, it should be part of the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) to prevent using the Container as a [Service Locator](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/). By placing the classes inside your *Composition Root* it becomes merely a [piece of infrastructure](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/).

So the feature is excluded deliberately, but the library can be extended by making use of the `ResolveUnregisteredType` event:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies;

public static class AutomaticFactoryExtensions {
    public static void RegisterFactory<TFactory>(this Container container) {
        if (!typeof(TFactory).IsInterface)
            throw new ArgumentException(typeof(TFactory).Name + " is no interface");

        container.ResolveUnregisteredType += (s, e) => {
            if (e.UnregisteredServiceType == typeof(TFactory)) {
                e.Register(Expression.Constant(
                    value: CreateFactory(typeof(TFactory), container),
                    type: typeof(TFactory)));
            }
        };
    }

    private static object CreateFactory(Type factoryType, Container container) {
        var proxy = new AutomaticFactoryProxy(factoryType, container);
        return proxy.GetTransparentProxy();
    }

    private sealed class AutomaticFactoryProxy : RealProxy {
        private readonly Type factoryType;
        private readonly Container container;

        public AutomaticFactoryProxy(Type factoryType, Container container)
            : base(factoryType) {
            this.factoryType = factoryType;
            this.container = container;
        }

        public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg) {
            if (msg is IMethodCallMessage) {
                return this.InvokeFactory(msg as IMethodCallMessage);
            }

            return msg;
        }

        private IMessage InvokeFactory(IMethodCallMessage msg) {
            if (msg.MethodName == "GetType")
                return new ReturnMessage(this.factoryType, null, 0, null, msg);

            if (msg.MethodName == "ToString")
                return new ReturnMessage(this.factoryType.Name, null, 0, null, msg);

            var method = (MethodInfo)msg.MethodBase;
            object instance = this.container.GetInstance(method.ReturnType);
            return new ReturnMessage(instance, null, 0, null, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the extension method above, you can do the registration for the factory in a way very similar to Ninject's registration:

```
container.RegisterFactory<IBarFactory>();
```

That's it.

Comment: How can you unit test such a factory, if it is dependent on the Container?

Comment: @Boris: You would typically have a few unit/integration tests that test the container's configuration ([example](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/diagnostics.html) because verifying the container [is important](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#verify-configuration). In the same way as described here you can test this factory. Since those tests test the container, you obviously need an initialized container.

Comment: @Steven I'm curious if there is a dotnet core analogue for your extension method here?